# HttpServletRequest request.getAttribute () gives null on jsp page

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

Hello I'm trying to pass data from servlet to jsp page, but get a null.
Please tell me where I go wrong?
Here is my code:

MyConnection.java

```
  public void doGet (HttpServletRequest inRequest,
             HttpServletResponse outResponse) throws ServletException,
             IOException {
 
             inRequest.setAttribute ("ST", "QWERTY");
             RequestDispatcher dispatcher = inRequest.getRequestDispatcher ("/index.jsp");
 
             out.print ("\ n" + dispatcher);
 
             dispatcher.forward (inRequest, outResponse);
}
```

index.jsp

```
<% @ page contentType = "text / html" pageEncoding = "UTF-8"%>
<% @ page language = "java" import = "java.util. *"%>
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title> JSP Page </ title>
     </ head>
     <body>
         <form action="MyConnection" name = "myForm" method="Get">
             <% = (String) request.getAttribute ("ST")%>
             <% out.println (request.getAttribute ("ST"));%>
         </ form>
     </ body>
</ html>
```

Comment: You probably don't invoke the servlet at all, and go directly to the JSP. Check the address in the adress bar of your browser. BTW, the path of the JSP in the servlet is probably wrong: I doubt the JSP file name starts with a blank space. Also, forget definitively about scriptlets. Use the JSP EL and the JSTL: `${ST}`.

Comment: file name does not start with a blank space, this is copy-pase error.
adress in browser next: "http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/index.jsp"

I need used servlets, this is a task)

Answer (score 0):

The address in the browser is the address of the JSP, so the JSP is executed. To execute the servlet, you have to put the address of the servlet in the address bar.